# Distorsión de diseño en android

Tags: android, diseño

¿Por que cuando abro mi aplicación en una tablet y/o otros celulares se distorsiona todo el diseño?

Cuando abro mi aplicación en mi celular se mueve algunos cajones de texto, botones, entre otros.

Aca les dejo una demostración del XML que estoy tratando de acomodar: (por razones personales borre el nombre):

---

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline4"
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="6dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="364dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="83dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Personal"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCodPersonalR"
        android:layout_width="244dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView19"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnBuscarR"
        android:layout_width="47dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@mipmap/lupa"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="327dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout2"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout5" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="258dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="230dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.305">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Nombre:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvNombreR"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNombreR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView16"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvFotoR"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Puesto:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvPuestoR"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvNombreR"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPuestoR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView20"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvFotoR"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.148" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Area:"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvAreaR"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView16"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvPuestoR"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.483" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAreaR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tvFotoR"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView20"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.184" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputLayout5"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFotoR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="151dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.311" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Foto"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tvNombreR"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.709"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/digitalClock"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvFotoR"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputLayout5"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="360dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout8"
    android:layout_width="171dp"
    android:layout_height="196dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ACRelojR"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputLayout5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView24"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:text="Scanner"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ACRelojR"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="372dp" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCodEpiR"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="102dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/epinsaqr"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ACRelojR"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tvContenidoR"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="404dp" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvContenidoR"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/background_light"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/digitalClock"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="525dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<AnalogClock
    android:id="@+id/ACRelojR"
    android:layout_width="168dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="200dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/digitalClock"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<DigitalClock
    android:id="@+id/digitalClock"
    android:layout_width="113dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout8"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.164"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="left" />

<android.support.constraint.Barrier
    android:id="@+id/barrier5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:barrierDirection="left" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="20dp" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Y asi es como esta en mi Android Studio(me gustaría que salga tal cual en la Tablet también)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Bueno les compartiré la solución que estoy haciendo y a mi me está resultado.

Lo que hice es que en cada formulario o ventana o vista o como gusten llamarlo, le agrego un Layout Horizontal, o vertical o un Frame layout de acuerdo al diseño que se necesita, la cuestión esta en NO dejar ningun elemento en el "aire" y asegurarnos de que estos layout estén bien sujetos a las paredes de la ventana. 
Le dejo una muestra, espero y les sirva :)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]